# Socket throwing code into a loop when terminating application

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets

In the method below, the desktop application that sends messages to this method was terminated and in the Eclipse console the server was STILL running and the method got thrown into a LOOP that started to fill up the Eclipse console pretty quickly.

I'm very new to socket programming so pardon what is probably a stupid question but in my stack trace line 503 states that there was a java.io.EOFException which occurred when the desktop app was terminated but then in the method below, the catch statement in the else { } portion started a loop of logging errors.  This is inherited code and I could really use some help on how to best handle this type of error.  Any suggestions/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Here is the stack trace:

> WARN | Channel-Socket-1-ReceiveQueuer-0 |                com.sharpbancsystems.channel.ActiveSocket |   503 |2013-10-01 08:04:22,406| - java.io.EOFException
>       at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:180)
>       at com.sharpbancsystems.channel.ActiveSocket.blockUntilGetMessageLength(ActiveSocket.java:498)
>       at com.sharpbancsystems.channel.ActiveSocket.blockUntilGetMessageBytes(ActiveSocket.java:456)
>       at com.sharpbancsystems.channel.ActiveSocket.blockUntilReceiveMessage(ActiveSocket.java:268)
>       at com.sharpbancsystems.channel.ReceiveQueuer.run(ReceiveQueuer.java:113)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Here is the method code:

```
protected int blockUntilGetMessageLength() {
    final byte[] b = new byte[2];
    try {
        dataInputStream.readFully(b, 0, 2);
    } catch (final IOException ex) {
        if (this.shouldTerminate) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            LOGGER.warn(FormatData.formatStack(ex));
            synchronized (socket) {
                socket.notify();
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    LOGGER.trace("Received 2 bytes: " + new String(b));
    return ((((b[0]) & BYTEMASK) << BYTESHIFT) | ((b[1]) & BYTEMASK));
}
```

Comment: You call `socket.notify()` to wake up another thread. What does that other thread do? And who sets the `shouldTerminate` flag?

Comment: What does `blockUntilGetMessageLength(ActiveSocket.java:498)` do when it gets a 0 back from `blockUntilGetMEssageLength()`?

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for your input and questions.  I realize I did not give you a lot of info and for that I apologize. The logging code needs to be re-factored and I'm working on that right now.  I probably should not have posted so early.  Again my apologies and thanks for your input and time.  Regards.